# DFROBOT I2C 16x2 Arduino LCD Display Module I2C communication interface

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

What is the proper connection to the I2C communication interface (e.g., JST Jumper 4 Wire Assembly) of the DFROBOT I2C 16x2 Arduino LCD Display Module (SKU:DFR0063)? I wish to connect 4 wires assembly directly to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is schema how to connect it and example how to use it, also link to needed library. Hope this helps.

https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/I2C/TWI_LCD1602_Module_(SKU:_DFR0063)

Anyway - I2C is prettty standardized interface, so googling any I2C schema for your type of Arduino will work as for connection - just connect SDA (A4) to SDA, SCL (A5) to SCL, GND to GND and VCC to VCC as writen on the module interface.

There are also lots of correct results for googling the module name - just google SKU:DFR0063 and you get many of correct links. On first page every second link contains link for the library, those others just refers to the manufacturer in text.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23083)

Comment: Esential part is connect I2C (connect the same name pins on module & Arduino), download library from manufacturer and use it usual way. The link ghoes to manufacturer wiki about the product, so it should not perish easy). Anyway I added this description to answer. Took me longer, then to google for the name of module and click the link for download library in every second google result.